# How do I import an external Js file and run it in my App.vue file

Tags: vue.js, import, vuejs3

I have a JS file for a drop down menu and need it to continue my code and I am unable to import it into my "App.vue" file and run the js code.

I tried generally importing it and it did not work.
App.vue

```
<template>
<Header />
<h1>Welcome to Building Page</h1>
<div class="dropdown">
     <div class="select">
          <span class="selected">Figma</span>
          <div class="caret"></div>
     </div>
     <ul class="menu">
          <li>Framer</li>
          <li>Sketcher</li>
          <li>Invision Studio</li>
          <li class="active">Figma</li>
          <li>Adobe</li>
     </ul>
</div>
</template>


<script lang = "ts">
import Header from './components/HomeHeader.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header
  }
};

</script>

<style>
*
{
     box-sizing: border-box;
     font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
     color: white;
}

p{
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

header
{
     position: absolute;
     top: -20%;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
     transition: 0.6s;
     padding: 40px 100px;
     z-index: 100000;
     font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

header.sticky
{
     padding: 5px 100px;
     background: #fff;
}

header .logo
{
     position: relative; left: -500;
     font-weight: 700;
     color: #fff;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 2em;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     transition: 0.6s;
}

header ul
{
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
}

header ul li

{
     position: relative;
     list-style: none;
}

header ul li a
{
     position: relative;
     margin: 0 15px;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #fff;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     font-weight: 500px;
     transition: 0.6s;
}

.banner
{
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100vh;
     background-size:cover;
}

body
{
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(255, 255, 255))
}

.dropdown {
  min-width: 15em;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20em;
}

.dropdown * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.select {
  background: #2a2f3b;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px #2a2f3b solid;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.3s;

}

/*
  Clicking Styles
*/
.select-clicked {
  border: 2px #26589a solid;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.8em #26489a;
}

.select:hover {
  background: #323741;
}
.caret {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/*
  Rotate Drop Down Menu
*/

.caret-rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0.2 0.5em;
  background: #323741;
  border: 1px #363a43 solid;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5em  1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  color: #9fa5b5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 0.7em 0.5em;
  margin: 0.3em 0;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background: #2a2d35;
}

/*
 Active
*/

.active {
  background: #23242a;
}

/*
  Open Style.
*/

.menu-open{
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

h1 {
  position:relative; right: -150px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 750px;
}
h2 {
  position:absolute; top: 0px; right: 100px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  height: 200px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

</style>
```

dropdown.js (file i am attempting to import into "App.vue")

```
const jsddm = () => {
    const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');

    dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
        const select = dropdown.querySelector('.select');
        const caret = dropdown.querySelector('.caret');
        const menu= dropdown.querySelector('.menu');
        const options = dropdown.querySelectorAll('.menu li');
        const selected = dropdown.querySelector('.selected');


        /*
        Multiple Drop Down Menu Function
        */
       select.addEventListener('click',() => {
        select.classList.toggle('select-clicked');
        caret.classList.toggle('caret-rotate');
        menu.classList.toggle('menu-open');
       });
       options.forEach(option => {
        option.addEventListener('click', () => {
            selected.innertext = option.innerText;
            select.classList.remove('select-clicked');
            caret.classList.remove('caret-rotate');
            menu.classList.remove('menu-open');
            options.forEach(option => {
                option.classList.remove('active');
            });
            option.classList.add('active');
        });
       });
    });
}

export default jsddm;
```

Any help would as to how I can import my "dropdown.js" file into "App.vue" and run it together.

Comment: "I tried generally importing it and it did not work" - where? You preferably shouldn't, as Vue app is dynamic, DOM elements may exist at one point but not exist at the other. Stick to native Vue solutions, especially since the script is small. The problem with this specific script is that it will cause memory leaks, this is one of the reasons why this is avoided